# php statement inside another php statement?

Tags: php

In the example below, I've inserted `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` within the larger statement. However, it produces a blank screen. How would I get this to work?

```
<?php next_posts_link('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/next-page.png" />') ?>
```

Comment: does it "echo" it?. That might be the reason it's not working. You might have to echo it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Also enable `error_reporting` when you get blank screens. Or at least look into the `error.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
next_posts_link('<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/images/next-page.png" />');
?>
```

You have to concatenate the „parts“ via the [dot-operator (`.`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

The screen was blank because you had a `Parse Error` in there and `display_errors` is probably off in your `php.ini`

Comment: Thank you, there is no more blank screen but this produces two separate lines: one for the template url and one for `/images/next-page.png`. Is there a way to get it to produce one line (i.e. one image url)?

Comment: `bloginfo('template_url')` probably contains a newline at the end

Comment: Anyway to get around that without altering the core code?

Comment: You could wrap it into `trim`

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `<?php`.

```
<?php next_posts_link('<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/next-page.png"') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php next_posts_link('<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/images/next-page.png" />') ?>
```

This is the code you want.